# Assign query result into a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want assign result into a session

c# code

```
       protected void BindData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-677TN4G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=homework;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable FromTable = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    string cmdstr = "Select CourseName from Staff where FacultyNumber=@idd";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", Session["id"].ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);   
    DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    DataList1.DataBind();

}
```

so how i can do it i try to do

```
        Session["id"] = cmdstr.Text;
```

but it not work

i do it like this but not work

I do it like this

```
       protected void BindData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-677TN4G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=homework;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable FromTable = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    string cmdstr = "Select CourseName from Staff where FacultyNumber=@idd";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", Session["id"].ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);   
    DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    Session.Add("Staff", ds.Tables[0]);
    DataList1.DataBind();
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Course Name is : " + Session["Staff"].ToString();

}
```

and the output is

> Course Name is : Table

not the selected value

Comment: Could you please add more information about your requirements, `cmdstr ` is a string variable it doesn't contains a property called `Text`

Comment: As I see `cmdstr` is a string, not a text box control. Where your `Session["id"]` value comes from?

Comment: i want the session comes from the result from the table and show it in label

Comment: What you are getting in `Label1.Text`; what you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the result is a `DataTable` no problem you can store this DataTable to the session as well. Let `staffData` be the DataTable that you are populating from the database,

```
Session.Add("Staff", staffData);  // Adding datatable to the session
```

In your case you are using `ds` is used as a DataSet and you are accessing `ds.Tables[0]` to bind the grid. in this case you can use something like: `Session.Add("Staff", ds.Tables[0]);`.

Later you may come up with another question that how can I retrieve this DataTable from the session, Here I'm adding the answer for that as well.

```
DataList1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["Staff"];
```

Comment: i change it and the are some problem check the code please